# Prevent completing-read from exiting with nil

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm reading the documentation on `completing-read`, but I can't find a way to do what I need.

It says that:

> (completing-read PROMPT COLLECTION &optional PREDICATE REQUIRE-MATCH
>   INITIAL-INPUT HIST DEF INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD)
>
> . . .
>
> REQUIRE-MATCH can take the following values:
>   - t means that the user is not allowed to exit unless   the input is (or completes to) an element of COLLECTION or is null.
>   - nil means that the user can exit with any input.
>   - `confirm' means that the user can exit with any input, but she needs   to confirm her choice if the input is not an element of COLLECTION.
>   - `confirm-after-completion' means that the user can exit with any   input, but she needs to confirm her choice if she called
>   `minibuffer-complete' right before `minibuffer-complete-and-exit'
>   and the input is not an element of COLLECTION.
>   - anything else behaves like t except that typing RET does not exit if it   does non-null completion.

What I need to do is something like:

```
(completing-read "What kind of project should I create? "
  haxe-project-kinds
  (lambda (x) (message "predicate: %s" x)) t)
```

This shouldn't return `nil`, because if it does, it's an error - but I don't want to run the user through all other options until she discovers that she got the very first one wrong.

More than that, the behaviour advertised in the documentation doesn't match what really happens. It makes absolutely no difference what I put in the 4'th argument's position, the behaviour is unchanged.

Comment: Couldn't you just loop until input is non-nil?

Comment: When the require-match as argument si a function (as in your exemple), this function won't be called, but only use as a value that is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which part of what you want is not satisfied by your sample code, so it's hard to give a good answer.  My guess is that you want to prevent the user from hitting RET with an empty answer.  Indeed `completing-read` does not prevent that, even with `require-match` set.  The way this is usually handled is by using a non-nil value for the `default` argument, in which case this value is returned when the user just hits RET.

If that's not good enough, then you're probably going to have to use `minibiffer-with-setup-hook` and in the hook, setup a special keymap you've created for this purpose where RET is bound to a new function that signals an error if the minibuffer is empty and calls `minibuffer-complete-and-exit` otherwise.

Comment: @wvxvw: Personne ne t'oblige à utiliser `(interactive (list ...))`.  Tu peux utiliser `(interactive (let ((arg1 (completing-read ...))) (unless arg1 (error ..)) (list ...)))`.  La forme est simplement `(interactive EXP)` où EXP est une expression qui renvoie la liste des arguments.

Comment: @wvxvw: Duh! sorry about the French.